# Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE Databinding: Error when validating submitted form

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Since upgrading my webapplication from Spring 3.0.5 to 3.1.1 I have to face some serious errors when validating my form-beans. My previously configured validator(s) doesn't work any more like they should. The problem is that the method ***getFieldValue(String fieldname)*** from Class ***org.springframework.validation.Errors*** does not return the original binded bean value like it should (and was before).

This is what my form-bean looks like:

```
public class PersonBean extends BaseFormBean {

private String firstname; // getters and setter omitted...

    private String lastname; // getters and setter omitted...

    private Integer age; // getters and setter omitted...

    public PersonBean() {}

    @Override
    public void validateForm(Errors errors) {
        WebValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstname", "validator.requiredvalidator.lbl", "field required");
        WebValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "lastname", "validator.requiredvalidator.lbl", "field required");      
        WebValidationUtils.rejectInvalidIntValue(errors, "age", "validator.std.age", "invalid age", false);
    }
}
```

The WebValidationUtils-class that gets invoked has some standard methods for checking bean properties. The error occurcs only on non-String values, like the property age which is of type Integer. It also happens on Collection(s).

The following snippet shows how Integer values are validated in my utils-class:

```
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
...

public abstract class WebValidationUtils {
...
    public static void rejectInvalidIntValue(Errors errors, String field, String errorCode, String defaultMessage){
        Assert.notNull(errors, "Errors object must not be null");
        Object value = errors.getFieldValue(field); // returns the string value (type: java.lang.String)
                Class<?> fieldType = errors.getFieldType(field); // returns the class Integer!
        if (value == null || !value.getClass().equals(Integer.class) || ((Integer)value).intValue() <= 0){
                errors.rejectValue(field, errorCode, null, defaultMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

The bean itself has the correct value bound...

Do I have to configure some additonal spring beans in my context-servlet.xml do achieve the same bevahior like it was in 3.0.5?

Edit: The official [Spring Doku](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#getFieldValue%28java.lang.String%29) for the method "getFieldValue(...)" says

> Return the current value of the given field, either the current bean property value or a rejected update from the last binding.

So I don't have a clue why this method returns a String-value instead of the propagated bean value of type Integer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you have a binding error so `getFieldValue()` return `FieldError.getFieldValue()` that return the value that causes the binding error.  This is the expected behavior.

You can get the value that hold the property using `getRawFieldValue()` instead. This method always return the value using the `PropertyAccessor`.

Comment: ok, that did the trick. I had to use the other interface named org.springframework.validation.BindingResult in my validation class.
With this interface the method getRawFieldValue(String field) was accessible and I could read the original value of the bean property. but I don't have a clue why the update from the spring framework leads to this curious behaviour?

thx a lot jose!